# Changes in Antlr Grammar for Java

Tags: java, antlr4

I have started using ANTLR to build a parser and lexer for clone detection and removal system. 
I want to build a grammar to not to distinguish between private, public and protected keywords because I want to consider them as same things but when I try to do this it doesn't tokenize my input properly.

I have taken my grammar .g4 file from the [link](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) and did some modifications in it as below.

```
PRIVATE        : 'public' || 'private' || 'protected';
RETURN        : 'return';
SHORT         : 'short';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
PRIVATE        : 'public' || 'private' || 'protected';
```

is not correct. It could be rewritten as this:

```
PRIVATE
 : 'public' 
 |
 | 'private' 
 |
 | 'protected'
 ;
```

In other words: it matches an empty string.

You probably want to write this:

```
PRIVATE : 'public' | 'private' | 'protected';
```

A bit of a strange name, btw: `PRIVATE`. I'd expected something like this instead:

```
MODIFIER : 'public' | 'private' | 'protected';
```

or use a parser rule:

```
modifier : PUBLIC | PRIVATE | PROTECTED;

PUBLIC : 'public';
PRIVATE : 'private';
PROTECTED : 'protected';
```